# error "Index was out of range" in razor application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had this error when use upload file with razor page :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

the error occurred here

```
var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Category category)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var fileSavePath = "";
        var fileName = "";
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("../../Uploads/" + fileName);

        uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);


        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post, 
                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Path)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field create-Bt3">
       @FileUpload.GetHtml(
          initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
          allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
          includeFormTag: false,
          uploadText: "Upload")
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means, that the `Request.Files` collection does not contain any item.

You can check with the `Count` property for the number of files uploaded:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
}
```

Check with fiddler what the browser is sending - maybe its an issue with the `FileHelper`

Comment: I checked the count and it returned 0

Comment: Yes, that was expectable :) The question is, what is the browser sending? Check teh response with fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: how can I use it I installed but I cannot understand what it will do?

Comment: Just start it and then try to upload a file with your app - it acts as a webproxy and will display the http request and response. In the response you should see wheather the browser sends the file data or not